# How can I create nonexistent subdirectories recursively using Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, recursion, subdirectory

I am creating a quick backup script that will dump some databases into a nice/neat directory structure and I realized that I need to test to make sure that the directories exist before I create them. The code I have works, but is there a better way to do it?

```
[ -d "$BACKUP_DIR" ] || mkdir "$BACKUP_DIR"
[ -d "$BACKUP_DIR/$client" ] || mkdir "$BACKUP_DIR/$client"
[ -d "$BACKUP_DIR/$client/$year" ] || mkdir "$BACKUP_DIR/$client/$year"
[ -d "$BACKUP_DIR/$client/$year/$month" ] || mkdir "$BACKUP_DIR/$client/$year/$month"
[ -d "$BACKUP_DIR/$client/$year/$month/$day" ] || mkdir "$BACKUP_DIR/$client/$year/$month/$day"
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49263/recursive-mkdir

Answer (score 520, accepted):

You can use the `-p` parameter, which is [documented as](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mkdir):

> -p, --parents
>
> no error if existing, make parent directories as needed

So:

```
mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR/$client/$year/$month/$day"
```

Comment: @bmargulies - Holy crap that was way simpler than I thought =P

Comment: Upvoted because you're a deletionist. Oops, already did about a year ago!

Comment: It doesn't work if user has no right to read one of intermittent folders

Comment: `alias mkdirs=mkdir -p`

Comment: Is there a way to set permissions recursively too?

Comment: @saeed-neamati `chmod -R`

Answer (score 73):

```
mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR/$client/$year/$month/$day"
```

Answer (score 27):

While existing answers definitely solve the purpose, if you’re looking to replicate a nested directory structure under two different subdirectories, then you can do this:

```
mkdir -p {main,test}/{resources,scala/com/company}
```

It will create the following directory structure under the directory from where it is invoked:

```
├── main
│   ├── resources
│   └── scala
│       └── com
│           └── company
└── test
    ├── resources
    └── scala
        └── com
            └── company
```

The example was taken from [this link](https://gist.github.com/y2k-shubham) for creating an [SBT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sbt_(software)) directory structure.

Comment: You may want to explain what `{...,...}` is in bash and why what your doing makes sense. A short explanation of the *brace expansion* would be beneficial to other users. A "you can do this" and get "this" leaves a bit to the imagination.

Comment: I agree with @DavidC.Rankin. This answer is perfect IMHO, but it needs explaining what the bracket notation actually does.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
mkdir -p newDir/subdir{1..8}
ls newDir/
subdir1 subdir2 subdir3 subdir4 subdir5 subdir6 subdir7 subdir8
```

Comment: This will just create 8 sub-directories in `newDir/`.