# issues in changing the dbpath in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i was having problem in starting up my mogodb server..(in ubuntu 16.04 LTS)
i type in the command "monogod" in the terminal and this is what i get.....
   ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
   Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.

i understand that this means that the directory /data/db/ does not exist so to resolve it i type in .... mongod --dbpath /data/db/
but once again i get the same error. i've googled the error many times but to no avail
can someone please help.. i am entirely new to this whole thing...

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

"ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist" means that the directory does not exist.

You need to make the directory.

Try:

`mkdir -p /data/db`

If you get a "permission denied" error, run:

`sudo mkdir -p /data/db`

and then type in your administrator/root password.

Read more about [creating directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731767/how-to-create-nonexistent-subdirectories-recursively-using-bash).