# How to create multiple directories using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am new to shell script, I am trying to create multiple directories using script at specific locations.i have no idea about that, i am giving here what i have tried so far ,

```
directory_name="/home/usw9bls7/lib1"

if [ -d $directory_name ]
then
echo "Directory already exists"
else
mkdir $directory_name
fi

I have to create directory at locations
"/home/usw9bls7/config1"
"/home/usw9bls7/DNQ/lib1"
"/home/usw9bls7/DNQ/config1"
```

Plesae help

Comment: @ImAtWar please  check my edited post

Comment: use '-p' as option to `mkdir` to create missing intermediate directories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create nonexistent subdirectories recursively using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1731767/608639)

Comment: Hi Mandrek, consider using metacharacters and --parents of mkdir to simplify things, I've provided you an example, hope it helps to your purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use "if" statements for such simple task, use "-p, --parents" of mkdir to create several directories that doesn't exist and ignore existing ones.

Combine that capability using metacharacters to expand subfolders creations.

In this example I've created the next structure with one command:

```
-/home
   |---/usw9bls7
          |------- DNQ
                     |---- lib1
                     |---- config1

user@DESKTOP-RR909JI ~
$ mkdir -p /home/usw9bls7/DNQ/{lib1,config1}

user@DESKTOP-RR909JI ~
$ ls -ltr /home/usw9bls7/DNQ/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 user user 0 jun. 29 20:17 lib1
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 user user 0 jun. 29 20:17 config1
```

None of these directories existed before in my environment (except for /home). Anyway if you want to create the script try simplifying things with this.

Comment: You didn't have a `/home` folder? *Gasp*

Answer (score 0):

Using brace expansion if you use `bash`:

```
directory_name="/home/usw9bls7/lib1"

if [ -d "$directory_name" ];then
   echo "Directory already exists"
else
    mkdir -p  /home/usw9bls7/{config1,DNQ/lib1,DNQ/config1}/"$directory_name"
fi
```

Example: with `echo` command.

```
echo /home/usw9bls7/{config1,DNQ/lib1,DNQ/config1}
/home/usw9bls7/config1 /home/usw9bls7/DNQ/lib1 /home/usw9bls7/DNQ/config1
```

Comment: getting : command not found
./test.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./test.sh: line 8: `fi'

Comment: Your line endings may be corrupted.

Comment: give output of `echo $SHELL` and try adding `#!/bin/bash` to first line of your script.

Comment: @PS  now giving -bash: ./test.sh: /bin/ksh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Portable POSIX solution (works in /bin/ksh, /bin/sh, and /bin/bash)

```
#!/bin/sh
parent_directory="/home/usw9bls7/lib1"

for directory_name in config1 DNQ/lib1 DNQ/config1
do
  if [ -d "$parent_directory/$directory_name" ]
  then
    echo "Directory already exists"
  else
    mkdir -p "$parent_directory/$directory_name"
  fi
done
```

This merely loops over your given names and then makes them.  I added the `-p` option so that it will silently create missing parents like DNQ as needed.

Note that if these exist as files rather than directories, you'll get errors from mkdir.  At least you'll get something.

Answer (score 0):

Pass them all to `mkdir -p`:

```
mkdir -p \
"/home/usw9bls7/config1" \
"/home/usw9bls7/DNQ/lib1" \
"/home/usw9bls7/DNQ/config1"
```

If you're super performance-conscious, you can test them for existence from the shell first. Here's what I'm doing in my shell lib:

```
all_eh()
{
    local predic a; predic=$1; shift
    for a; do
        $predic "$a" || return 1
    done
}
mkdir_p() { all_eh 'test -d' "$@" || mkdir -p "$@"; }
```

This is faster if all the directories exist because `test` (or `[` ) is a shell builtin (in practically all shells) and so doesn't cost you the usual 1-2ms fork/exec overhead.