# Creating multiple folders and their subfolders in one go

Tags: linux, directory

I have the following folder structure and have 20-30 subfolders inside the last folder and I wanted to see what is the quickest way to come up with all these folders on my machine using linux commands.

My Folder structure:

```
Folder A ---- Project A -----Sample 1
Folder A ---- Project A -----Sample 2
Folder A ---- Project A -----Sample 3
```

So you can see above, there are three levels - Folder, then Project and then Samples.

iF I use a text file, or whatever you recommend, what will be the best way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create nonexistent subdirectories recursively using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731767/how-to-create-nonexistent-subdirectories-recursively-using-bash)

Comment: @IoCalisto, I think these fall into slightly different use cases. The other question doesn't cover multiple directories at the leaf directory.

Comment: Yes, I want subfolders with specific names. How do I create such hierarchy with linux

Answer (score 0):

To create exactly what is described above, this Bash one-liner should work.

`for i in {1..30};do mkdir -p Folder_A/Project_A/Sample_"$i";done` creates:

```
├── Folder_A
│   ├── Project_A
│       ├── Sample_1
│       ├── ...
│       ├── Sample_30
```

If you want something more complex, you could do something like

`for f in top_level_1 top_level_2; do for i in sub_folder_1 sub_folder_2;do mkdir -p Folder_A/$f/$i;done;done`

or make this a full bash script and [execute it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2178699/4975404)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for f in mid_level_1 mid_level_2;
        do for i in sub_folder_1 sub_folder_2;
                do mkdir -p parent_directory/$f/$i
        done
done
```

This gives this structure:

```
├── parent_directory
│   ├── mid_level_1
│       ├── sub_folder_1
│       ├── sub_folder_2
│   ├── mid_level_2
│       ├── sub_folder_1
│       ├── sub_folder_2
```

You can change what directories are made by changing the list of directories after the word `for`.  Instructions for bash for loops can be found [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/)

If you need anything even more complex, use these principles and try writing a bash script that can do it.  I think that is where the fun of programming/scripting really is.

Comment: what does "I" mean here when you write "for I"? Is there a way to list in a text file to just create ll the folders so that fit can follow the hierarchy listed in the text file?

Comment: "i" is used in the for loop, like used in most programming languages.

Comment: Okay, but with the above command, how would it know what folder name to give to my subfolders.i don't want just random 30 folders to be created. I want with specific names.

Comment: I'll update my answer to make it more clear how you do that.

Comment: Thanks Mason, will wait for the updated answer. It will be helpful to me. Thanks

Comment: @mywayz, Hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks Mason, I will try this. today and get back to you